# making <td> visible if another <td> is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, show-hide

So I have a below, the code can be seen below:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td id="first">itemOne</td>
        <td id="firstClicked">itemOneInfo</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td id="second">itemTwo</td>
        <td id="secondClicked">itemTwoInfo</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I want #firstClicked and #secondClicked to be hidden when #first and #second  are clicked, I want #firstCLicked and #secondClicked to appear. How would I make that happen? So far I have

```
$('#firstClicked').css('visiblilty','hidden');
$('#first').click(function() {
    $('#firstClicked').css('visibility','visible');
});
```

But this isn't working. Plus, even if this works, I'd have to do the same thing for #second, and i'm planning on creating more 's as well so I dont want to repeat the same code several times. Is there any better way of doing this?

Comment: You were missing a `#` before your code was edited.  Make sure you've got that fixed!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd recommend using jQuery's `hide` and `show` functions, as well as the `on` function for event handling. jQuery's main power is that it makes things "just work" across browsers, so using `hide` will let the library choose what to do in order to make that action happen, rather then you having to second guess yourself. Example:

```
$('#firstClicked').hide();
$('#first').on('click',function() {
    $('#firstClicked').show();
});
```

In addition, in your original code, you have a few mistakes:

```
$('firstClicked').css('visiblilty','hidden');
// should be:
$('#firstClicked').css('visibility','hidden');
```

However, as you're worried about having to duplicate your code, you could do the following:

HTML:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td id="first" class="clickable">itemOne</td>
        <td id="firstClicked"><div class="initiallyHidden">itemOneInfo</div></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td id="second" class="clickable">itemTwo</td>
        <td id="secondClicked"><div class="initiallyHidden">itemTwoInfo</div></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

JS:

```
$('.initiallyHidden').hide();
$('.clickable').on('click',function() {
    $(this).siblings("td").children(".initiallyHidden").show();
});
```

This way any element with a class `clickable`, when clicked, will look for a sibling with class `initiallyHidden` and show it

Edit: Updated example to deal with the issue raised in Christophe's comment.

Comment: -1 using hide() on a table cell is a really bad idea

Comment: That's a good point. Perhaps a better option would be to use hide() on a div inside the table cell?

Comment: Is there any way to do it by just using visibility: hidden and visibility: visible? Instead of show and hide?

Comment: Probably, I think the reason the code you posted didn't work was because of the syntax errors I mentioned.

Comment: @user2719875 you may use visibility: hidden and visibility: visible.. but then again.. what's the point of using jQuery?

Comment: Ah, okay youre right.. so I got it to work, but now, when hovering over the .clickable <td>'s, the mouse cursor doesn't change to a clickable cursor like how the cursor normally changes when hovering over a clickable link. How would I make it so that the mouse cursor recognizes that it is clickable?

Answer (score 0):

**Updated:**

```
using display none on a table cell is a really bad idea – Christophe
```

Solution: use `<span> or <div>` element inside `<td>`

Try this:

```
$('#firstClicked span').css('display','none');
$('#first').click(function() {
    $('#firstClicked span').css('display','block');
});
```

Or this:

```
  $('#firstClicked span').hide();
    $('#first').click(function() {
        $('#firstClicked span').show();
    });
```

Working full code:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(e) {
$('#firstClicked span').css('display','none');
$('#first').click(function() {
    $('#firstClicked span').css('display','block');
});

$('#secondClicked span').hide();
$('#second').click(function() {
    $('#secondClicked span').show();
});

});
</script>

</head>
<body>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td id="first">itemOne</td>
        <td id="firstClicked"><span>itemOneInfo</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td id="second">itemTwo</td>
        <td id="secondClicked"><span>itemTwoInfo</span></td>
    </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('tr').find('td:first').next().css('visibility','hidden');
$('tr').find('td:first').css('cursor','pointer');
$('tr').find('td:first').click(function() {
    $(this).next().css('visibility','visible');
});
```

find('td:first') points to the first cell of each row.

find('td:first').next() points to the second cell of each row.

This addresses the last part of your question:

> i'm planning on creating more 's as well so I dont want to repeat the same code several times

Answer (score -1):

What about:

```
<script>

function show(div) {
    document.getElementById(div).style.display = 'block';
}

</script>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td id="first" onclick="show('firstClicked')">itemOne</td>
        <td id="firstClicked" style="display:none">itemOneInfo</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td id="second" onclick="show('secondClicked')">itemTwo</td>
        <td id="secondClicked" style="display:none">itemTwoInfo</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```